# Making Flanges Around an Existing Mesh Based on a User-Defined Path

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, 3d-printing, curve-modifier, boolean-modifier

I'm using Blender to modify statues for mold making. I have this issue where I need to create and 3D print flanges based on the statue geometry. Here are two example images. In the images, I quickly took cube and modified it to match the approximate location of the flanges I want.

[image: View 1] [image: View 2]

Now, I know how to use a boolean operator to take the difference and get the outline of the statue. But, in most of my cases, the flanges need to be curved in very specific ways. The next image shows a dramatized example path for this example. I need to create a very thin plate that matches that curve, but the curve needs to be based on the statue's mesh. Is there an easy way to do this? Let me know if I need to clarify anything! Thanks!

[image: Example Path]

Comment: How do you know what "curves" are needed from that view?

Comment: I need to manually mark the "curves". They typically need to not overlap with detailed features, like ears or eyes, or text.

Comment: Can't you model the boolean object around the detailed features?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that

Answer (score 2):

Your question sounds to me you need just a thin plate to separate mold parts, right?
If so, I don't think boolean is needed here.

---

Add *Curve* object, switch to *Edit* mode *Delete* curve, take **Draw** tool (free-hand pen), under properties switch to **Surface** ... draw a shape over your model ...

[image]

**Convert to Mesh** ... since some points are a bit overfloating you can fix that by **Shrinkwrap** modifier > *Apply*. Select all points **Extrude** (E), **Scale** (S) ...

[image]

That is all you need I guess (if I understood your question :) ).

[image]

For a flange to be 3D printed add Solidify modifier > Apply.

---

Note: Similar can be achieved with *Grease Pencil* object. Stroke follows surface precisely, *Convert to Curve*, *Convert to Mesh*, *Extrude&Scale*.

Comment: Thanks! You were correct, it's just the flanges. I'm not printing the molds. I'm waiting until the bounty is almost expired before a choose an accepted answer! But this one seems to be the most straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

This method should work for symmetrical models. However, if you need to work with asymmetrical models it can be adapted without too much issues I believe. Let's work with this model. First, make sure both the model and the 3D cursor is in the center of the scene. If you need to, you can snap the 3D cursor using *Shift+S* and clicking *Cursor to World Origin*.

[image: dragon-head]

Now, I'm going to create an 'empty' curve. *Shift+A*, select *Curve*, then *Bezier*. Afterwards, go to edit mode, select all verts (*A*) and delete them (*X*). This is our empty curve.

Snap your view to an axis, so you can easily draw your curve. Still in the edit mode of the curve, select *Draw* tool (not the very similar *Annotate*). On the top or in the N-panel, make sure the depth is set to *Cursor*. Draw the line you would like to cut.

[image: draw-curve]

Convert your curve to a mesh (Object mode > *Object* > *Covert* > *Mesh*). Back in Edit mode, select everything (*A*), extrude to side (*E*),  and scale on the axis of symmetry so all of the statue is cut.
[image: extrude-mesh]

Use *Solidify* modifier to achieve give the cutting object some thickness. Even really small numbers are enough, you just need a manifold object. Now, select the head in the and use *Boolean* modifier set to *Difference*, and select your cutting object as the *Object*. Apply the modifier.

[image: cut]

To use this method for asymmetrical model, just create two cutting objects, one from each side, and merge these two objects in the middle.